# Facebook SDK C# - try to post a link through facebook graph api but got (FacebookApiException - #100) Invalid parameter

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing following code for posting a link to my wall from c# desktop application, but it returns (FacebookApiException - #100) Invalid parameter

```
 FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
    Dictionary<string, object> postArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    postArgs["message"] = comment;
    postArgs["link"] = "https://www.google.com/";
     fb.Post("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed", postArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.

If I change the link to be the link in my Website => site url it works (i.e. the url of the application).

I believe they url in the link, you want to use, can be added to the App Domains section of the basic app settup.  I have had mixed results with this.

Answer (score 0):

you must turn off the **Stream post URL security option** in the dashboard of your app: https://developers.facebook.com/apps , clic on settings and then migrations.

[image: Dashboard]

See more information in the **Migrations > Stream post URL security** bullet : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#surfacearea